# can find where git default username is set

Tags: git, ssh

I have been using git command line successfully for a very long time. Today I tried installing the git desktop, along the way, there was a step where it says current git needs to be uninstalled. after which, I seemed to be stuck with my personal git username. When I git clone from my own repo in github, no username password was needed. When git clone or git pull from my client's repo, it complains can't even find the repos's url.

I checked to make sure no user.name or user.email exist in `git config --global --list`. I even set the global user.name to the one needed for the client repo, but still the same result.

`ssh -vT git@github.com` shows that it tries to look up `id_rsa`, but fails, so it ends up with `Permission denied (publickey)`. I checked, and the `id_rsa` file is not there. I don't know what is the right way to set up one.

Where can the secret setting be on my Macbook which is supplying my default `user.name` during a git command?

Answer (score 0):

> `ssh -vT git@github.com` shows that it tries to look up id_rsa, but fails

When you do that from the git client shell, check what `$HOME` refers to: [ssh would seek public/private keys in `$HOME/.ssh`](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-1-check-for-ssh-keys).
The [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) might use a different path for `$HOME`, or for those settings.

Comment: nothing wrong with $HOME. I am saying I currently don't see a id_rsa in .ssh. should I create one?

Comment: @user1058511 yes, because ssh will look for `id_rsa(.pub)` in `$HOME/.ssh`

Comment: apparently ssh is in case you want to use ssh instead of https. In my case that is irrelevant. the important thing is why all git commands seems to be stuck using my default user name and not prompting me for user name password.